# Can't use indexes in PHP on my server

Tags: php

Whenever there is a '[' in my code, my server returns an error; it runs locally however.

```
function get_date($get_date_zone = "UTC") {
    date_default_timezone_set($get_date_zone);
    return getdate()['mday'] . "/" . getdate()['mon'] . "/" . getdate()['year'];
}

print get_date();

?>
```

I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/eliteshi/public_html/deve/test.php on line 5
```

Could there be something wrong with my code? Or am I looking at something server-side?

Comment: What php version it is? I believe that dereferencing isn't available < 5.4

Comment: Ah, it's 5.3.27 - is there an alternative way I should be doing it? The server isn't mine to update :S

Comment: What you're doing is available only in PHP 5.4+ I think. So in you local host you must be having a more recent version of PHP whie in your server you have an older version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to dereference return values (that's the fancy name for doing `doSomething(args)[key]`) was only added in PHP 5.4. Your server probably doesn't have it.

In this case, though, you'd be wiser to use a temporary variable:

```
$getdate = getdate();
return $getdate['mday']."/".$getdate['mon']."/".$getdate['year'];
```

Comment: I bet you missed it because of hat that slid on the eyes. ;-)

Comment: Something like that XD

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you have PHP version `< 5.4`. Instead of this `getdate()[...]` syntax, try with:

```
$date = getdate(); 
return $date['mday'] . "/" . $date['mon'] . "/" . $date['year'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Only possible since php 5.4. You are probadly using an older version of PHP.

You have to put it in a seperate variable first:

```
$var = getdate();
$var['mday'];
```

Comment: The correct function is `getdate()`. `get_date()` is OP's custom function